# Fluentd does'nt store data on influxdbv2

Tags: influxdb, fluentd, syslog, rsyslog, td-agent

I'm trying to store syslog on influxdbv2 using fluentd (td-agent). The configuration of td-agent is:

```
<match system.**>
    @type influxdb2                           
    url             http://influxdb:8086
    token           my_token
    bucket          bucket_name
    org             org_ID
    use_ssl         false
</match>

<source>
  @type syslog
  port 42185
  tag system
</source>
```

I added `*.*  @127.0.0.1:42185` in the rsyslog.conf file. All data seems to arrive correctly, but in influxDB there is nothing. Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue, changing the value of the field `org`, from `org_ID` to `org_name`